# Datagridview refresh data keeps old values there

Tags: c#, datagrid, datasource, overlapping

I'm developing a small piece of SW using Windows Forms. I'm trying to populate a datagridview with the content of a list using its dataSource property.

The binding seems to be correct but I'm having this behaviour. Looks like the old data is not removed and the new one is place above the old one, overlapping both texts. I'm not able to determine the reason.

[You can see this behaviour here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LDFF.png)

[And here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vg5q.png)

Every time I need to update my datagridview I'm calling:

```
 private void updateAforoInDatagridView()
 {
        parentForm.dataGridView2.DataSource = null; 
        parentForm.dataGridView2.DataSource = presenter.getTurnosState(dayBookings, dayTurnos);
        parentForm.dataGridView2.Refresh();
        parentForm.dataGridView2.Update();
 }
```

This is the object I'm trying to place in the datagridview

```
public string Entrada { get => entrada; set => entrada = value; }
public string Salida { get => salida; set => salida = value; }
public string Nombre { get => nombre; set => nombre = value; }
public decimal Aforo { get => aforo; set => aforo = value; }
public decimal Libre { get => libre; set => libre = value; }
```

First four properties come from a database and the last one is added manually by me after making some calculations here:

```
internal List<Turno> getTurnosState(List<Booking> dayBookings, List<Turno> dayTurnos)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dayTurnos.Count; i++)
    {
        var currentTurno = dayTurnos[i];
        var bookingsForCurrentTurno = dayBookings.Where(booking => booking.TurnoName.Equals(currentTurno.Nombre) && booking.TurnoTime == DateAndTiming.getTimeFromString(currentTurno.Entrada)).ToList();
        currentTurno.Libre = currentTurno.Aforo - bookingsForCurrentTurno.Sum(booking => booking.NumberOfPeople);
    }

    return dayTurnos;
}
```

Comment: The data in the DGV is always coming from the same source presenter.getTrunosState().  Where are you updating the source?

Comment: Just edited the original question.

Comment: You are reading from a database and never changing the database so you always get the same values.  To get different data you need to change the variable values for dayBookings and dayTurnos.

Comment: What about the overlapping texts in the cells? Any idea?

Comment: Is the grid using a custom cell implementation?

Comment: Problem was solved by removing and adding a new datagridview..

Comment: That's a new one to me and googling turned up nothing so you may want to answer your own question so the next person can benefit .

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got rid of this strange behaviour by removing the datagridview from the view and adding a new one. I can't say precisely which property caused this behaviour but luckily it's been solved.

Thanks.